# Building axios url to get from router params with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to build a string to use with axios to get certain data from an api.  I can't seem to figure out using computed or mounted for this scenario.  My current code keeps telling me that my returnurl is not defined.  Any assistance would be great.  I don't know if even trying to build the url correctly to begin with.

Thanks

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "GroupList",
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      groupName: this.$route.params.group,
      swipedata: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get(returnurl).then(response => (this.swipedata = response.data));
  },
  computed: {
    returnurl() {
      return (
        this.returnurl = "http://localhost:5000/" + this.$route.params.group
      );
    }
  },
  components: {}
};
</script>
```

My router section for it:

```
{
  path: "/groups/:group",
  component: GroupList,
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```js
axios.get(returnurl).then(response => (this.swipedata = response.data));
```

to

```
axios.get(this.returnurl).then(response => (this.swipedata = response.data));
```

You simply forgot a `this` :)